# Question regarding Mulesoft and DataWeave

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

Is is safe to say the most important and most difficult part for Mulesoft development is to master the DataWeave lang?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not.

Yes, it is important part but you can totally eliminate it and write transfrormations/mapping in other languages like Java, Groovy, JavaScript, Python. I would say half of apps don't need it at all - they simply connect or manage other APIs or sources of information.

Yes, it is easy to use/write/change with DW scripts but other parts are even more important. Community Edition of Mule has no DW but is is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

Though what Alex says is correct. Mulesoft CE does ships dataweave. Any expression in mule ce or we is a dataweave expression and you can still use the set-payload operation to write your transformations in data weave in ce.